# Get the value of the next input

Tags: jquery

```
<form method="post" id="formFinish2"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="finish" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="id" class="finishId" value="2" /> 
</form> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(":checkbox[name='finish']").click(function() { 
        id = $(this).closest('input.finishId').val(); 
        alert(id); 
        $("#formFinish".id).submit(); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Alerts me `undefined`. I would like it to alert me `2`, which is coming from the input that has the class `finishId`, next to the checkbox you clicked on.

Comment: Aside from @Saeed's answer, you should fix the syntax error `$("#formFinish".id)` should be `$("#formFinish"+id)`.

Comment: Why not simply submit the parent? `$(this).closest("form").submit();` Then you don't need that extra input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `closest` only searches DOM **upward**. In other words, `closest` starts searching by **father element**, then **grandfather element**, etc.

You should use `siblings` instead.

```
$(this).siblings('input.finishId').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

Beside the siblings function you could also us the next function. See http://api.jquery.com/next/